# Setting the backslash's catcode

Tags: catcodes

For fun, I want to change the backslash's catcode from 0 to 12. However, I can't seem to make it work. Here's my current MWE, which gives an error "improper alphabetic constant":

```
\catcode`\textbackslash=12
```

I know that `\textbackslash` is not the right one, however, I can't seem to find a command for a program backslash. Could someone please help? By the way, I have the *forward* slash's catcode set to 0 just in case the problem is that I need to change the character for commands.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\textbackslash` is just for typesetting.  As the name says, it's a *text* command, so it just prints the character `\` from the current font, and isn't of any use for anything other than that.

You are looking for:

```
\catcode`\\=12
```

---

The syntax for the `\catcode` primitive is `\catcode<number>=<catcode>`, and it sets the catcode of the character whose ASCII code is `<number>` to `<catcode>`.  This means that you could also use:

```
\catcode 92=12
```

However it's a mouthful to remember all the ASCII codes, and your code becomes quite a lot less readable.  To improve on that TeX allows you to specify a number using an “alphabetic constant”.  To do that, the `<number>` should start with a `` ` ``, followed by the character token you want to make a number of. Valid alphabetic constants are `` `a ``, `` `* ``, etc.

The only problem is that a catcode-0 character (here the backslash) doesn't produce a token, so neither:

```
\catcode`\=12
\catcode`\ =12
```

do what you want (the first one changes the catcode of `=`, and the second the catcode of ).  To specify these characters, TeX allows you to escape the character with a backslash, so to specify the alphabeitc constant `` `\ `` you prefix it with another backslash: `` `\\ ``, so:

```
\catcode`\\=12
```

Comment: So, the ` allows you to change `\\` from newline to a backslash? I didn't know that! +1 and accept

Comment: Also, I knew that `\textbackslash` was used for typesetting. However, it was the best I could come up with.

Comment: @Someone Yeah, that's a primitive TeX syntax. Any time TeX is looking for a number, if such number starts with a `\``, the next token can be either a character, or a character preceded by a backslash. In the case of ``\\`` you _need_ the preceding backslash because a single backslash doesn't make a token. Note that this works: ``\catcode`|=0 \catcode`\\=12 |catcode`\=3 |show\`` because after the second `\catcode`, the backslash is just a character, so you don't have to prefix a backslash anymore.

Comment: Does it mean that I could type `\\ and have it be a backslash? Or would it be a "open single quote and newline"?

Comment: @Someone The latter. The special \`\\ syntax only expands to `92` (the ASCII code of ``\``) when TeX is looking for a number. Everywhere else it will mean open quote and ``\\``. Compare the output of ``(\number`\\)(`\\)``.

Comment: So does the `` ` `` method work for characters that are not ASCII?

Comment: @youthdoo Only if you're using an unicode-aware engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX). On pdfTeX, non-ascii are special